# express js app.get callback function

Tags: javascript, express, get

hi I am confused about the syntax of the get route function there seems to be 2 versions
here is some example code

first one:

```
app.get('/users', function(req,res){
     ...
});
```

second one:

```
app.get('users/:name', function(req,res,next){
     ...
     if(users[req.params.name])
      ....
     else
         next()
});
```

I am confused as to what is the next function in the second one. And why it isn't necessary in the first one

Thanks

Comment: Does my answer help you at all?  Can I clarify it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back it up a bit and look at express as a middleware stack.  Literally, a stack.

You have a series of `app.use`, `app.get`, and `app.post` calls.  Together, they form a chain.  When a request comes in, express figures out which middleware functions match the URL pattern and calls the first one along with a reference to the next one.  This is how separate, independent middleware objects get linked.

For example, there is a middleware that parses the query string and stores it as an object in `req.query`.  There is a middleware that parses the `Cookie` header and creates cookie objects.  There is a middleware that provides access logging.  Again, these get linked together as a chain.  If the middleware functions are independent, they do their work and then pass control to the next link in the chain by calling `next()`.

```
app.use(express.logger();
app.use(express.responseTime());
app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session());
app.use(i18n.handle);
app.use(app.router);
```

The reason routes do not have to use next is because routes are generally the end of a chain.  There is nothing left to do after a route.